# Application receive a SIGBART error while running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

when i run my application it receive a SIGBART error in main.m class.

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
     return retVal;
  }
```

The application returns an error as "Program Received a signal SIGBART" in UIApplicationMain().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just "Quit" your simulator and try again.

Or give some more details.

Comment: The asker has not mentioned Simulator anywhere in her question. So how did you know that she is testing on her simulator?

Answer (score 1):

I think error is not in main.m, but the error displays like that. Please go and check the error stack trace in Xcode's console and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

debug your code on which event you got SIGBART or look in the output there should be some exception some where else